# How to configure supabase to use a http cookie to store the session?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js, cookies, supabase

I'm currently storing the old access and refresh token inside a http only cookie from a Next JS route handler that I can recall to set the previous session again (which I do in the middleware), however supabase seems to always make it non-http. Is there a way to configure it to be http so it is less vulnerable to attacks or is there something else to do?

I'm using Next JS v13 + supabase js + auth helpers for the framework.